# Phonegap: Detect navigator.notification.alert is open or not

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

In my apps(using phonegap), i am using navigator.notification.alert(), to show custom message for the user end. when i get the alert message in the window, that time if i click the back button, i just want cancel that alert window and stay on the same page. I want to know how to check whether the alert box is open or not. If its open just want to cancel the alert box in phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but by back button, you mean cancel? If so, you can create a callback function (or simply set this value to null) as in the example below:

```
navigator.notification.alert(
'You are the winner!',  // message
alertDismissed,         // callback
'Game Over',            // title
'Done'                  // buttonName
);


function alertDismissed() {
    // do your magic
}
```

Read more about [phonegap's alert / confirms here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can achieve this through PhoneGap... What you can always do is create a boolean and set it to true when the alert is showing. In my experiences though, you are better off using the confirmation and not alert. Alert, for some reason, allows the user to click anywhere on screen and the alert will disappear. Confirmation, on the other hand will force the user to click on the button.

hope that helps